# Using valuePtr() etc to allocate space for Eigen3 SparseMatrix

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am trying to initialize `Eigen::SparseMatrix A` by using `malloc` like this

```
A.valuePtr() = static_cast<T*>(std::malloc(nnz*sizeof(T)));
A.innerIndexPtr() = static_cast<int*>(std::malloc(nnz*sizeof(int)));
```

but I get the error

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

for both statements. In case it matters, the function containing the lines takes a `Eigen::SparseMatrix<T, Eigen::RowMajor>` by reference.

Can anyone help me with this? I'm using g++ 5.2.

EDIT:
The function `valuePtr` of class `SparseMatrix` is

```
inline Scalar* valuePtr() { return &m_data.value(0); }
```

`Scalar` is a template paramter. `m_data` is a protected variable of type `CompressedStorage` whose method `value(size_t i)` returns a **reference** to the ith member of its internal data array.

```
 inline Scalar& value(size_t i) { return m_values[i]; }
```

So, I concluded that `valuePtr()` returns the address of the first element of an array. I should, then, be able to allocate space for that array by malloc.

In case someone is interested, I include a link for reference - please see lines after 84, and 131. [Eigen3 SparseMatrix class](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/SparseMatrix_8h_source.html)

Comment: Never used Eigen, but I am fairly certain that this is not how one initializes Eigen matrices. You should read the docs.

Comment: I agree with @BaummitAugen, however may i reccomend you avoid malloc entirely and use new and delete (or better, a C++11 shared_ptr, or unique_ptr.

Comment: @JohnBargman I used malloc because that's what they use internally in Eigen. I assumed it would be better for their destructor.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I know this is non-standard. I need this because I have my own sparse matrix implementation that I want to use with Eigen's sparse LU decomposition routines.

Comment: It's very unlikely (and I mean very) they would need you to allocate data to be used internally by their class (this pretty much violates memory-ownership and object-orientation semantics). Are you are supposed to be doing what you're doing?

Comment: @AdityaKashi - with all due respect, I think you might be going about this incorrectly - Can't you create a new class that inherits from the Eigen one, then overload it's methods / constructor?  
If not, the very best you can hope for is a hack, and one that will no-doubt be very buggy.

Comment: @AdityaKashi I think you may actually want this : http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MappedSparseMatrix.html

Comment: ITT: Stop messing around with library internals, use the documented interfaces, in this case construct the matrices with the appropriate constructors.

Comment: @JohnBargman Thanks for your time; I'll take a look.

Comment: @AdityaKashi I'm really glad I was able to help you! I've updated my answer to help you understand why what you did didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely due to you trying to assign a object to a method!

You lines equate to:
`A.valuePtr() = Sometype_Pointer;`, `A.valuePTR()` will Call the `Eigen::SparseMatrix::valuePTR` method(function) of object A.

If this method returns a pointer (`T* A::valuePtr()`) then the pointer returned isn't what you want! the method would be returning a *rvalue*; an *rvalue* is not a *lvalue* that isn't the pointer contained in A, rather it's a **temporary copy** of the pointer.
You can't assign anything directly to it, just like you can't touch the people on a television screen.

I'm making a massive assumption that your trying to do what I described above, and that would be impossible unless that method looked like this:

```
T ** Eigen::SparseMatrix::valuePTR()
{
    return &T;
}
*A.valuePtr() = static_cast<T*>(std::malloc(nnz*sizeof(T)));
```

However, note that using malloc is considered very, very out-dated for c++ objects, something like this line would be more *correct*
    *A.valuePtr() = static_cast(new T[nnz]));

## [edit/]

Honestly I'm trying very hard to understand what your code is supposed to accomplish. And most people (including myself) will not be familair with this "Eigen" class. Though I think you may very-much misunderstand how it's supposed to be used.

Could you possibly provide a link to documentation, or an example of how your creating / using this class?

## [Edit 2/]

After some research I came across [This article](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/sparse-iterators/) as well as [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777017/how-to-wrap-eigensparsematrix-over-preexistant-3-standard-compress-row-colum-a), could it be possible you need to use a [MappedSparseMatrix](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MappedSparseMatrix.html)

## [edit 3/]

`inline Scalar* valuePtr() { return &m_data.value(0); }` will return a *rvalue* pointer. This isn't the object held in m_data, nor is it the pointer used internally. It's a temporary **copy of a pointer to an existing object**, trying to say "make this temporary copy point to something else" doesn't make sense.

`inline Scalar& value(size_t i) { return m_values[i]; }` In this case, the method returns a *reference to an object*, a reference is not a pointer - (though the `&` often confuses people).
A reference can be understood as *the original object*, you don't need to *dereference* a reference. Consider the following.

```
int A;
int * A_p = &A;
int & A_r = A;
int & A_r_2 = *A_p;

//de-reference the pointer (to create a reference)
*A_p = 10;  //A == 10
//Assign directly to A (via the reference)
A_r = 12; // A == 12
//assign directy to A (via the reference to A, that was taken from A_p
A_r_2 = 15; // A == 15
//attempt to de-reference a reference
*A_r = 10; //ERROR, A_r is not a pointer.
```

In short, The reference being returned isn't a pointer to the object (that already exists), rather it **is the object**. This would allow you to set the object to something, or call methods on the object using the `.` operator, however you cannot re-allocate something that already exists, and as such is an error.

Please consider reading this article on the difference between rvale and lvalue's in C++ [understanding rvalue and lvalue](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c)

Comment: The right approach is indeed to use a `MappedSparseMatrix` (with 3.2), or better a `Map<SparseMatrix<double> >` with Eigen 3.3.

Comment: @John Bargman Thanks, MappedSparseMatrix works - it has a convenient constructor to set the arrays. But I still don't understand why my earlier method does not work. As I explained in the edit, I should get an lvalue when I call valuePtr().

Comment: @AdityaKashi, what I said holes true for valueptr, it returns a pointer, however that pointer is a 'rvalue' copy of the original - assigning to it doesn't make sense as it won't effect the original.

Comment: @AdityaKashi, as for the value(int) method, that returns a reference to an object - but the object is the actual object. and int& is not the same as int*. I'll update my answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

After @John Bargman told me that the way I think about rvalues and lvalues is wrong, I thought about it and tried this:

```
class A
{
    char* str;
public:

    // This function returns a literal (constant) of type char* 
    // (just an address), not a pointer variable
    char* getstr() {
        return str;
    }

    char getchar(const int i) const {
        return str[i];
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    // the RHS can't be assigned to a literal, we need a variable in the LHS
    a.getstr() = static_cast<char*>(malloc(10*sizeof(char)));   // ILLEGAL!

    // this assigns the address contained in str to mstr.
    char* mstr = a.getstr();

    // after this, mstr will have nothing to do with A::str; the former 
    // will have been re-assigned to a different address
    mstr = static_cast<char*>(malloc(10*sizeof(char)));

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        mstr[i] = '0';
    mstr[9] = '\0';

    // The following line segfaults as no storage has been allocated to A::str
    cout << a.getchar(1) << endl;   // runtime error!

    free(mstr);
    return 0;
}
```

Now I understand that the function `SparseMatrix::valuePtr()`, like `A::getstr()`, returns a literal of some address type; it does not return a lvalue. Trying to assign something (in this case, the address of the start of a block of memory returned by `malloc`) to a literal (in this case, some address like 0x233ff554) is meaningless. I think I understand now how it works. Thanks @John Bargman!